# Create own Datasources

Tags: xpages

Is there any information on how to create your own datasources for xpages? I'm busy developing a java API for a system of ours and I would like to be able to use the data as a datasource within xpages.

Comment: Data sources in XPages are a very specific topic and for XPages developers this question makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Abhinav-sarkar Data sources in XPages are a very specific topic and for XPages developers this question makes a lot of sense and isn't much for debate (like in J2EE spring vs EJB3 vs. whatever)

Comment: This question is a very relevant topic for XPages and should not have been closed.

Comment: I agree this is a relevant question. but it should ask how to create a dinamyc datasource in xpages. The answer though is very relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was a Lotusphere 2011 session SHOW107 that walked you through the steps. Read about it on [Jim's blog](http://blog.sequill.com/2011/02/xpages-data-source-control-for-relational-databases/), the [BleedYellow community](http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/06b53a4f-1d53-4919-842d-51d6c8be697d), an excellent [slideck](http://www.slideshare.net/pdhannan/ad116-01) from Paul (and related) as well as [SHOW107](http://www.slideshare.net/NotesSensei/show107-the-datasource-session-take-xpages-data-boldly-where-no-xpages-data-has-been-taken-before) itself.

One caveat: The data sources don't show their fields in the Domino Designer. If you want that functionality then, instead of looking at *com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.ObjectDataSource* you would subclass the DominoDocument and more or less overwrite all functions.

Comment: 478 slides.. Tonight I am going to sleep very late.

Comment: They will keep you awake, promise!

Answer (score 2):

You could look in the source code of the extension library. There you will find the class *com.ibm.xsp.extlib.model.ObjectDataSource* as an easy example.